# Can't install therubyracer-heroku in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, heroku, rubygems, therubyracer

I can't install therubyracer-heroku in Ubuntu 12.04. I have seen this error in one or two other places on the internet, but no solution. The command I run is:

```
sudo gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3'
```

The output is long, these are the last few lines (that contain the errors):

```
src/bootstrapper.cc: In static member function 'static bool v8::internal::Genesis::CompileScriptCached(v8::internal::Vector<const char>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::SourceCodeCache*, v8::Extension*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Context>, bool)':
src/bootstrapper.cc:1002:18: error: variable 'result' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
src/bootstrapper.cc: In member function 'bool v8::internal::Genesis::InstallNatives()':
src/bootstrapper.cc:1227:24: error: variable 'name' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [obj/release/bootstrapper.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
make: *** [build/v8/libv8.a] Error 2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
extconf.rb:9: Error compiling V8 (RuntimeError)
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick,

therubyracer-heroku and therubyracer versions 0.8.1 are ancient. Please try using the normal version of therubyracer at it most recent release, currently version 0.11.3

```
gem install therubyracer
```

or, if you feel you must stick to a particular version

```
gem install therubyracer -v 0.11.3
```